# Two Key HashSet?

Tags: java, hashset

I need a HashSet implementation where the elements are a **pair of Integers**
eg. `Set s = { {1,2} , {3,4} , {1,4}}`. Here the set s has 3 elements.

This kind of two key HashSet is needed in many situations like, I have a relation in my database where the candidate key is a combination of two columns.
Is there some library which already provides this? 
If no such implementation is available, then rather then implementing the entire data structure from scratch, will it be easier (and efficient?) to extend the HashSet implementation in Java?

Comment: Using `HashSet<int[]>` did not help because of the point raised by Adamski. So, created a data holder with a list of integers and provided equals and hashcode implementations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For this requirement I would create a data holder with the 2 integers as attributes and provide equals and hashcode implementations. Then put those objects in the Set.

Answer (score 1):

And won't it work to put an array with 2 elements as a member of the set? I.e.:

```
Set<int[]> s = new HashSet<int[]>();
s.add(new int[] {1,2});
s.add(new int[] {3,4});
```

or create a class `CandidateKey` which has two fields and a custom `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods?

That all said, are you sure you want to handle object-relational mapping (mapping from database to objects) yourself, rather than using a library like Hibernate or EclipseLink?

Comment: Will this actually work?  I would have thought that the default equals and hashCode implementation of an array would be identity-based.

Comment: they are, but in some cases it might be sufficient - I don't know whether his is such. That's why added the suggestion about a new class, where equals and hashcode are implemented properly.

Comment: The proposed int[] solution has a limitation. There is nothing that prevents you from adding arrays with fewer or more elements, e.g. int[] empty = new int[0]; or int[] triple = new int[] {1, 2, 3};.

Comment: @matsev - and nothing prevents you from having candidate keys with more than 2 columns ;)

Answer (score 0):

An Integer List would work in this case:

```
Set<List<Integer>> s = new HashSet<List<Integer>>();
s.add((List<Integer>)Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {2,4}));
s.add((List<Integer>)Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {2,4}));
s.add((List<Integer>)Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {2,5}));
```

The`hashCode() and equals()`helpers are built into the `ArrayList` class.